# Is grounding needed when using adapter to phone?

Tags: ground, wiring, adapter, grounding

I am doing research on an audio plug. I wonder, is it a must to connect grounding circuit from handphone to the earphone if we use an adapter (image 1). Or can I do the connection like in image 2?

[Image 1](http://www.flickr.com/photos/87649514@N02/9732887039/)

[Image 2](http://www.flickr.com/photos/87649514@N02/9732887055/)

Comment: The links seems to be broken for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, stereo headphones use 3 wires: Left, Right, and common/return, which may be called ground. I'm assuming that you are referring to the common and not a separate ground.

If you don't connect he common, what you end up with is the two source channels connected in series, but **out of phase**, to the two earpieces, again in series but out of phase. The result is that any signal that is common to the two channels will cancel out and not be audible while signals not in common will be combined.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frLw2B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The practical result, on many pieces of music, is that the vocals, which are typically "centered" in the stereo signal will become inaudible. In fact, this is a trick that has been used in the past to remove vocals for recorded music. Unfortunately, you will also lose any instrument that is also centered.

On the other hand, if you are talking about a **4th** wire, a separate ground, you cab probably disconnect this without harm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its actually 4 contact audio plug, and the adapter in this case is just for extension. Blue ground wire are buried inside the adapter. Is it OK if I make the connection as image 2 for this type of plug?

Comment: Frankly, I'm having a hard time understanding your images. "Standard earphones" (stereo) are three wires (L, R and common). The only time I've seen 4 wires is if there is also a microphone.

Comment: Sorry because not explain details in the first post. the image just for reference, and the plug & standard earphone consist of L, R, MIC & Common.

Comment: In that case, you will need ALL 4 wires to be connected.